# Table error for selection in Java FX application

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

[image]I created an Inventory Management System. Everything is working expect whenever I add a new Product and selected associated part, the previous associated parts that were selected are pulled down. It should only be selecting and pulling down the new part selected.

How can I clear the memory of what we selected when the previous product was selected?

Thank you,
Kayla

[image]

```
package InventoryProgram.View_Controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import InventoryProgram.Model.Inventory;
import static InventoryProgram.Model.Inventory.getParts;
import InventoryProgram.Model.Part;
import InventoryProgram.Model.Product;
import static InventoryProgram.Model.Product.addAssociatedPart;
import static InventoryProgram.Model.Product.getAssociatedParts;
import static InventoryProgram.Model.Product.deleteAssociatedPart;

public class AddProductScreenController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField id;

    @FXML
    private TextField name;

    @FXML
    private TextField inv;

    @FXML
    private TextField price;

    @FXML
    private TextField max;

    @FXML
    private TextField min;

    @FXML
    private Button searchButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField search;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Part> partTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Integer> partID;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, String> partName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Integer> partInv;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Double> partPrice;

    @FXML
    private Button addButton;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Part> foundPartTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Integer> foundPartId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, String> foundPartName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Integer> foundPartInv;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Part, Double> foundPartPrice;

    @FXML
    private Button deleteButton;

    @FXML
    private Button saveButton;

    @FXML
    private Button cancelButton;

    @FXML
    private int productID;

    @FXML
    private String productError = new String();

    @FXML
    private String fieldError = new String();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        partID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("partID"));
        partName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        partInv.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inv"));
        partPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        foundPartId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("partID"));
        foundPartName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        foundPartInv.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inv"));
        foundPartPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        productID = Inventory.getProductIDCount();
        id.setText("Auto Gen: " + productID);
        partTable.setItems(getParts());
        foundPartTable.setItems(null);

    }

    @FXML
    public void searchPart(ActionEvent event) {
        String searchPartIDString = search.getText();
        if (searchPartIDString.equals("")){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Part Search Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("There were no parts found given your search variables.");
            alert.setContentText("Please enter a valid part to search for");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
        else {
            boolean found=false;
            try {
                Part searchPart = Inventory.lookupPart(Integer.parseInt(searchPartIDString));
                if (searchPart != null) {
                    ObservableList<Part> filteredPartsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    filteredPartsList.add(searchPart);
                    partTable.setItems(filteredPartsList);
                }
                else {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setTitle("Part Search Error");
                    alert.setHeaderText("There were no parts found given your search variables.");
                    alert.setContentText("Search variable entered does not match a valid part ID.");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                for (Part p : getParts()) {
                    if (p.getName().equals(searchPartIDString)) {
                        found=true;
                        ObservableList<Part> filteredPartsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                        filteredPartsList.add(p);
                        partTable.setItems(filteredPartsList);
                    }
                }
                if (found==false) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setTitle("Part Search Error");
                    alert.setHeaderText("There were no parts found given your search variables.");
                    alert.setContentText("Search variable entered does not match a valid part name.");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void addProduct(ActionEvent event) {
        Part part = partTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (part == null) {
            Alert nullalert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            nullalert.setTitle("Adding Part Error");
            nullalert.setHeaderText("The part could not be added.");
            nullalert.setContentText("Please select a part to add");
            nullalert.showAndWait();
        }
        else {
            foundPartTable.setItems(null);
            addAssociatedPart(part);
            foundPartTable.setItems(getAssociatedParts());

        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void deleteAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Delete Part");
        alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you want to delete the associated part?");
        alert.setContentText("Press OK to delete. \nPress Cancel to cancel deleting the associated part.");
        alert.showAndWait();

        if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK) {
            try {
                Part part = foundPartTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                deleteAssociatedPart(part.getPartID());
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Alert nullalert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                nullalert.setTitle("Part Delete Error");
                nullalert.setHeaderText("The part could not be deleted");
                nullalert.setContentText("A part must be selected to delete");
                nullalert.showAndWait();
            }
        }
        else {
            alert.close();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void saveAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String productName = name.getText();
        String productInv = inv.getText();
        String productPrice = price.getText();
        String productMax = max.getText();
        String productMin = min.getText();
        ObservableList<Part> foundParts = foundPartTable.getItems();

        fieldError = Product.emptyErrors(productName, productInv, productPrice, productMax, productMin, fieldError);
        if (fieldError.length() > 0){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Product Addition Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("The product could not be added");
            alert.setContentText(fieldError);
            alert.showAndWait();
            fieldError = "";
        }
        else {
            if (foundParts.isEmpty()) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Product Save Error");
                alert.setHeaderText("The product could not be saved.");
                alert.setContentText("Associated part must be selected.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            else {
                try{
                    productError = Part.partErrors(
                            Integer.parseInt(productInv),
                            Double.parseDouble(productPrice),
                            Integer.parseInt(productMax),
                            Integer.parseInt(productMin),
                            productError);
                    if (productError.length() > 0) {
                        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                        alert.setTitle("Product Add Error");
                        alert.setHeaderText("The product could not be added.");
                        alert.setContentText(productError);
                        alert.showAndWait();
                        productError = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        Product addProduct = new Product();
                        addProduct.setProductID(productID);
                        addProduct.setName(productName);
                        addProduct.setInStock(Integer.parseInt(productInv));
                        addProduct.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(productPrice));
                        addProduct.setMax(Integer.parseInt(productMax));
                        addProduct.setMin(Integer.parseInt(productMin));
                        foundParts = foundPartTable.getItems();
                        addProduct.setAssociatedPartsList(foundParts);
                        Inventory.addProduct(addProduct);

                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
                        Parent root = loader.load();
                        Scene s = new Scene(root);
                        Stage winMainScreen = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                        winMainScreen.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
                        winMainScreen.setScene(s);
                        winMainScreen.show();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void cancelAction(ActionEvent eCancel) throws IOException {
        try {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Cancel Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you want to cancel adding a new product?");
            alert.setContentText("Press OK to return to the Main screen. \nPress Cancel to continue adding a new product.");
            alert.showAndWait();

            if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK) {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
                Scene s = new Scene(root);
                Stage winMainScreen = (Stage)((Node)eCancel.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                winMainScreen.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
                winMainScreen.setScene(s);
                winMainScreen.show();
            }
            else {
                alert.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }

}
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="467.0" prefWidth="651.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="InventoryProgram.View_Controller.AddProductScreenController">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="65.0" text="Add Product" textFill="#18208d">
            <font>
                <Font name="Arial Bold" size="18.0" />
            </font></Label>
        <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="144.0" text="ID" />
        <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="37.0" text="Name" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="272.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="168.0" />
        <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="202.0" text="Inv" />
        <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="231.0" text="Price/Cost" />
        <Label layoutX="29.0" layoutY="260.0" text="Max" />
        <Label layoutX="163.0" layoutY="260.0" text="Min" />
        <TextField fx:id="id" disable="true" editable="false" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="139.0" promptText="Auto Gen - Disabled" />
        <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="168.0" promptText="Product Name" />
        <TextField fx:id="inv" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="197.0" promptText="Inv" />
        <TextField fx:id="price" layoutX="135.0" layoutY="226.0" promptText="Price/Cost" />
        <TextField fx:id="max" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="255.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="88.0" promptText="Max" />
        <TextField fx:id="min" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="255.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="88.0" promptText="Min" />
        <Button fx:id="saveButton" layoutX="535.0" layoutY="422.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAction" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="Save">
            <font>
                <Font size="10.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="cancelButton" layoutX="583.0" layoutY="422.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelAction" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="Cancel">
            <font>
                <Font size="10.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <TableView fx:id="partTable" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="76.0" prefHeight="128.0" prefWidth="300.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="partID" prefWidth="50.0" text="Part ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="partName" prefWidth="76.0" text="Part Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="partInv" prefWidth="91.0" text="Inventory Level" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="partPrice" prefWidth="83.0" text="Price Per Unit" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <TableView fx:id="foundPartTable" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="245.0" prefHeight="128.0" prefWidth="300.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="foundPartId" prefWidth="50.0" text="Part ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="foundPartName" prefWidth="76.0" text="Part Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="foundPartInv" prefWidth="91.0" text="Inventory Level" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="foundPartPrice" prefWidth="83.0" text="Price Per Unit" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <Button fx:id="searchButton" layoutX="413.0" layoutY="42.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#searchPart" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="Search">
            <font>
                <Font size="10.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <TextField fx:id="search" layoutX="464.0" layoutY="42.0" />
        <Button fx:id="addButton" layoutX="581.0" layoutY="211.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addProduct" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="Add">
            <font>
                <Font size="10.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="deleteButton" layoutX="581.0" layoutY="381.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteAction" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="Delete">
            <font>
                <Font size="10.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>

enter code here
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact mouse/keyboard actions which are involved in “add a new Product and selected associated part”?  Without the corresponding .fxml file, we cannot run your program in order to see the behavior for ourselves.

Comment: @VGR I added the main screen screenshot.  How this works is I click add to add a new part.  The parts that are added will show up on the top table of the Add Product screen. The user is meant to enter in product information, click the part that is associated with the product, and then click add. Then they click add, the part move to the bottom table which is the associated parts table. That table is populating with the same associated parts selected previously instead of starting fresh with a new product, Does that help? I can posted my FXML file as well

Comment: That seems to be caused by `foundPartTable.setItems(getAssociatedParts());`.  Please include the code for that method in your question.